# Can't undo git pull, not showing in reflog, need to undo pushes in the middle

Tags: git, svn, version-control

**What Happened**

I hired a developer 3 weeks ago to do the initial pages of my project. After that I cleaned his code (made 90% changes) and proceeded with the completion of the project. The other day, I hired him again to do one page (out of over 50 pages) of the project and trusted that he would have replaced his old code with the new one. He told me he pushed the changes so I can check his work.

Before I can pull, I wanted to push my changes, so I did a commit, and was prompted for a pull. So I pulled, and lo and behold, he forced all the old files to be pushed and the merges are all in favor of the newly pushed old files.

I wanted to undo the pull and just revert his commits, but it's not showing up in `git reflog`.

**Timeline of What I did**

1. `git commit -m "message"`
2. `git pull` and everything merged
3. `git reflog`, pull is not there

> ```
> 010cffa HEAD@{0}: commit: added ticket types, added analytics to events list
> 76867f4 HEAD@{1}: commit: added super required, and toaster to event
> 378799f HEAD@{2}: commit: app form
> ```

4. `git reset --hard 010cffa` nothing happens
5. `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` nothing happens
6. checked Source Tree
   [image: How to undo pull, source tree image]

**Need help on the following**

1. I need to undo the pull and restore my commit
2. and revert the hired developer's commits (3409eba and c759f12) and push my changes. I'll just ask him to push his changes after I push mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git checkout 3409eba
```

This work for me. it just git checkout and the last commit that you want.